# MQXR load balancing and request/response

Tags: mqtt, load-balancing, scalability

Is there any way MQXR can be considered scalable?

If the subscribers don't know who the publishers are - how is it possible to ensure load-balanced publishers can publish to load balanced subscribers?

If my terminology is all wrong I'm happy to be corrected.

Answer (score 0):

For any given message there is only ever a single publisher, so I'm not sure how you would get "load balanced publishers"

Load balancing **messages** across subscribers (to handle more messages than a single subscriber could process or to provide redundancy if a processing subscriber fails) can be handled by using Shared Subscriptions where the broker will ensure that each message is only sent to a single subscribe as part of a group.

Comment: Thanks - this is also an issue for us in that MQXR is at level 3. So "shared subscriptions" is not possible.

Comment: While Shared Subscriptions are an optional feature of MQTT v5, several brokers implemented versions of it at v3.1 I thought most of the IBM ones did this, I know IBM MessageSight definitely did. Also request messages with response topic headers are also a v5 feature.